# Why regexp_matches returns incorrect number of matches

Tags: regex, postgresql

OS: Debian 9.6.18-1 (64 bits)
PostgreSQL: 9.6.18 (64 bits)

Inside a table I have a text column that here for the sake of this example I name it **colval**. I want to selct rows where the colval column matches one of the following patterns:

```
1) variableName:*
2) variableName:partOfAValue*
3) variableName: *partOfAValue
4) variableName: *partOfAValue*
```

I have defined the following regular expression based on the four above-mentioned rules. Just to ease the reading I'm writing it here on several lines to show what part of the regular expression matches exactly which rule among the four above mentioned rules. As the text being searched is a part of a RESTful API log file, the character **:** may also be coded as *%3A* and the character asterisk may be instead coded as *%2A* (= html url encoding).

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*([:]|%3A) ---> this for matching 'variableName:'
(
        ([*]|%2A)             ----> *              matches the rule n° 1
    |   [^=*]+([*]|%2A)       ----> partOfAValue*  matches the rule n° 2
    |([*]|%2A)[^=*]+          ----> *partOfAValue  matches the rule n° 3
    |([*]|%2A)[^=*]+([*]|%2A) ----> *partOfAValue* matches the rule n° 4
)
```

I did a few tests and apparently this works and detects the matching rows.

Recently I was asked that in addition to the matching rows, also to provide for each row the number of times there was a match. So for example if I have the following row:

```
###var1:*########var2:enter*####
```

This should return two because there are two occurences/matches. var1 matches the rule 1 and var2 matches the rule 2. I checked the online documentation : [9.7. Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html#POSIX-EMBEDDED-OPTIONS-TABLE) to see whether there is any function in PostgreSQL allowing to count the number of times a string matches a given regular expression and I found the **regexp_matches** function which seems to be what I'm looking for. Yet when I tried with an example just to learn how it works, I was quite confused with the result. Here is my test case:

```
with tmptab as
(
    select 'line_01##var1:*#####var2:*val' as colval union all
    select 'line_02##var1:*val*' as colval union all
    select 'line_03' as colval union all
    select 'line_04' as colval union all
    select 'line_05' as colval union all
    select 'line_06#####var1:*###var2:*endval#####var3:*value*####var4:val*' as colval
)
select 
    colval, 
    regexp_matches(colval, '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*([:]|%3A)(([*]|%2A)|[^=*]+([*]|%2A)|([*]|%2A)[^=*]+|([*]|%2A)[^=*]+([*]|%2A))', 'i'),
    array_length(regexp_matches(colval, '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*([:]|%3A)(([*]|%2A)|[^=*]+([*]|%2A)|([*]|%2A)[^=*]+|([*]|%2A)[^=*]+([*]|%2A))', 'i') , 1)
from tmptab;
```

And here is the result

```
                             colval                              |           regexp_matches            | array_length
-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+--------------
 line_01##var1:*#####var2:*val                                   | {:,*#####var2:*,NULL,NULL,NULL,*,*} |            7
 line_02##var1:*val*                                             | {:,*val*,NULL,NULL,NULL,*,*}        |            7
 line_06#####var1:*###var2:*endval#####var3:*value*####var4:val* | {:,*###var2:*,NULL,NULL,NULL,*,*}   |            7
(3 lignes)
```

The output is correct in the sense that only line_01, line_02 and line_06 match one of the patterns in the regular expression. But I don't understand why there are seven matches in the returned array by regexp_matches? I have two matches for the first row, one for the second and four matches for line_06. Besides I don't understand the NULL values in the array.

Could you kindly make some clarification? It seems that either my regular expression is wrong or I misunderstand how regexp_matches works (or possibly both)

Is **regexp_matches** the correct way of counting matches in PostgreSQL while using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a match group and getting an additional element in the array for each pair of parentheses in your regex, notice how the last one is always `*`.  You could use non-capturing parens `(?:...)`, also you may need the global flag on lines with more than one match? (I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL)

> The regexp_matches function returns a text array of all of the
> captured substrings resulting from matching a POSIX regular expression
> pattern. It has the syntax regexp_matches(string, pattern [, flags ]).
> The function can return no rows, one row, or multiple rows (see the g
> flag below). If the pattern does not match, the function returns no
> rows. If the pattern contains no parenthesized subexpressions, then
> each row returned is a single-element text array containing the
> substring matching the whole pattern. If the pattern contains
> parenthesized subexpressions, the function returns a text array whose
> n'th element is the substring matching the n'th parenthesized
> subexpression of the pattern (not counting "non-capturing"
> parentheses; see below for details). The flags parameter is an
> optional text string containing zero or more single-letter flags that
> change the function's behavior. Flag g causes the function to find
> each match in the string, not only the first one, and return a row for
> each such match.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for your help. Indeed my mistake was the fact that I wasn't using (?: ...) so every substring at the position n inside parenthesis was indeed being captured separately in the nth position of the returned array. Also I added the 'ig' flags at the end to ignore the case ('i') and to get all the occurrences ('g'). After that all I needed was to write (select count(*) from regexp_matches(...)) as cnt to count the number of times there were matches for each row. Many thanks for your time and your help.